# Nested structure program using C

Tags: c, structure

My nested structure program is sending error.

Here I am using two structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    struct time
    {
        int min;
        int hour;
        int sec;
    };

    struct t
    {
        int c;
        struct time t1;
        struct time t2;
    }p;

    scanf("%d", &p.c);
    scanf("%d%d%d", &p.t1.minute, &p.t1.hour, &p.t1.second);
    scanf("%d%d%d", &p.t2.minute, &p.t2.hour, &p.t2.second);

    printf("%d%d%d", p.p1.min, p.p1.hour, p.p1.sec);
    printf("%d%d%d", p.p2.min, p.p2.hour, p.p2.sec);
}
```

After running this code I got the following error.

```
struct time’ has no member named ‘minute’
nested.c:17: error: ‘struct time’ has no member named ‘second’
nested.c:18: error: ‘struct time’ has no member named ‘minute’
nested.c:18: error: ‘struct time’ has no member named ‘second’
```

Comment: I understand you are a beginner, but try to use the same name that you used in definition: t1.min, t1.sec etc

Comment: The struct members are `min` and `sec` but you access `minute` and `second`.

Comment: I understand compiler warnings and error messages can be cryptic from time to time. But in this case: _"struct time has no member named second"_ should prompt you to look at the definition of `struct time`, and from that you should be able to deduce that indeed its members aren't called `second` or `minute`, but `min` and `sec`. Just replace `second` and `minute` on lines 17 and 18 with `sec` and `min` respectively. It's not rocket science

Comment: Somebody voted this up!?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
struct time
{
int minute; // change here
int hour;
int second; // change here
};

struct t
{
int c;
struct time t1;
struct time t2;
}p;

scanf("%d",&p.c);
scanf("%d%d%d",&p.t1.minute,&p.t1.hour,&p.t1.second);
scanf("%d%d%d",&p.t2.minute,&p.t2.hour,&p.t2.second);

printf("%d%d%d",p.t1.minute,p.t1.hour,p.t1.second);
printf("%d%d%d",p.t2.minute,p.t2.hour,p.t2.second);
}
```

should fix it - if something is not there, it can't be found ;)

Comment: struct t’ has no member named ‘p1’
nested.c:22: error: ‘struct t’ has no member named ‘p1’
nested.c:22: error: ‘struct t’ has no member named ‘p1’
nested.c:23: error: ‘struct t’ has no member named ‘p2’
nested.c:23: error: ‘struct t’ has no member named ‘p2’
nested.c:23: error: ‘struct t’ has no member named ‘p2’

Comment: changed p1 and p2 to t1 and t2

Answer (score 1):

The errors are quite clear, so I'll spare you the explanation of what they mean. If you are confused about the meaning of the errors after reading this answer, however, feel free to ask a question in the comments and I'll try to address it.

In `struct time` you have declared members `min` and `sec`, abbreviated forms of `minute` and `second`.

However, in the following code you use the unabbreviated forms `minute` and `second`; this is what your compiler is complaining about. For your convenience I've aligned your errors in the code below:

```
//            change minute to min           vvvvvv
scanf("%d%d%d",&p.t1.minute,&p.t1.hour,&p.t1.second);
//                   ^^^^^^           change second to sec

scanf("%d%d%d",&p.t2.minute,&p.t2.hour,&p.t2.second); // Repeat the process for this line
```

I also strongly recommend using `int main(void)` rather than `void main()`, as the former is strictly standard compliant and the latter is not, though your compiler may choose to support the latter as an extension.

It might also be a good idea to check the return value of `scanf`. For a call that you expect to read three values, the return value should be 3 when it succeeds. If it's 2, then you can only rely upon the first two values; the third will be garbage. If it's `EOF`, then your file has reached an end-of-file or error condition and you should stop trying to read from it, or `rewind`/`fsetpos`/`fseek`...

Answer (score 0):

May be this code will help you

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Employee
{
   char ename[20];
   int ssn;
   float salary;
   struct date
       {
       int date;
       int month;
       int year; 
       }doj;
}emp = {"amit",100,2000.50,{22,6,1990}};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
printf("\nEmployee Name   : %s",emp.ename);  
printf("\nEmployee SSN    : %d",emp.ssn);  
printf("\nEmployee Salary : %f",emp.salary);  
printf("\nEmployee DOJ    : %d/%d/%d", \
         emp.doj.date,emp.doj.month,emp.doj.year);  

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no variables named second and minute in your "time" struct. You have named them sec and min respectively.